# Errors in building INET in omnet++ 5.5.1

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, omnet++, inet

I have installed OMNeT++ 5.5.1 in ubuntu 18.04 successfully and it is working.

However, I am getting the following errors while building the latest version of INET. I followed  the instructions ( using the IDE) given in the document. Can anyone please help me to get ride of it? Thank you.

```
 /tmp/cc4FhpSO.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc4FhpSO.s: Fatal error: can't close ../out/gcc-debug/src/inet/visualizer/base/MediumVisualizerBase.o: No space left on device
Makefile:1754: recipe for target '../out/gcc-debug/src/inet/visualizer/base/MediumVisualizerBase.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-debug/src/inet/visualizer/base/MediumVisualizerBase.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tech/Downloads/inet4/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
"make MODE=debug -j2 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

20:48:19 Build Failed. 5 errors, 0 warnings. (took 11m:39s.915ms)
```

Comment: "No space left on device" Seriously, read the error first. Then, search for the error message online, maybe someone asked about it before and there's already a solution. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have free space in the disk:

> /tmp/cc4FhpSO.s: Fatal error: can't close ../out/gcc-debug/src/inet/visualizer/base/MediumVisualizerBase.o: **No space left on device**